# UI design - simple struct - how to implement

Tags: ios

How can I create the next (and simple) structure?
Is it just a tableView? or is it require assets ?
(I'm asking about the squares only, not about the text and icon at each row)
[image: rounded square with 3 rows]

Comment: simple UIbutton is enough for this concept

Comment: It's suppose to be textField, not a button

Comment: You can create this structure in many ways, buttons, tableView, UIView, use what method depends on your need. I think your question is too broad

Comment: choice is your bro, we can design in multiple ways,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this kind of design you should take one `UIView` with border and rounded corner.

Then add three textfield to it without border and add two another `uiview` of height 1 or 2 pixel(So it's looks like line) as a separator.

So by this you have ready this empty box with three textfield.